# How to get Data from JSON file, how can I parse the Date object to retrieve the data?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-material

```
export interface blog { 
  id: number; 
  name: any; 
  status: any; 
  active: string; 
  modifiedAt: Date; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How does your `JSON` file looks like ?
Second where from are you trying to get the `JSON` from a server or you have defined somewhere in your code as file.
Third you need to create an empty array of objects which at you it is `blog` and then to parse that `Json` to this `blog` and then through `*ngFor` you can easily show data in your `UI` which depends on your HTML.